# ASP.NET MVC app out of memory - System.Web.dll loaded into appdomain for each request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks

I have an ASP.NET MVC (the latest one) application that goes out of memory after approx. 1000 calls. I used different memory profilers like this:

1. make some calls
2. collect dump 1
3. make more calls
4. collect dump 2
5. compare dumps to check for new objects

What is strange is that there are absolutely 0 application objects in the diff. The only objects that are created are system ones, e.g. System.Web.Hosting.AspNetHostExecutionContextManager, System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager+AspNetAppDomainManager+AspNetAppDomainManagerImpl`2[[System.Web.Hosting.AspNetHostExecutionContextManager, System.Web], also strings, byte[] arrays, cross-domain support and some localization, but two above takes a LOT of output in the !DumpHeap output in WinDbg.

The number of missed objects for each dump diff is clearly related to the number of calls, e.g. 50 objects of each type and also for some types its 100 (50x2) objects.

The memory profiler that I used does GC before taking a dump and also I tried to do GC manually for each call, no change.

In the OOM state the worked process takes about 450MB of memory so it's not that big.

I suspect this is somehow related to the async requests because I see leaking objects like CrossDomainAppSink.

Another clue is that WinDbg (as well as Fusion) shows this

```
CLR:(C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll) 
Rejecting native image because it failed the security check. 
The assembly's permissions must have changed since the time 
it was ngenned, or it is running with a different security context.
```

for each request it seems. So I suppose I get OOM because there's a lot of System.Web assemblies stuck in the appdomain. Settings breakpoint for AspNetHostExecutionContextManager sets a LOT of breakpoints inside each of these modules. This does not happen for other assemblies.

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on here or how to move further? I'm a bit stuck on how to find out who's creating these objects and why they are kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the leak - it was AppDomain not being unloaded (it was created in the constructor and then immediately re-created). By accident the assembly loaded into the AppDomain contained a reference to the System.Web.dll and thus I had these web-related objects in memory.

Allocation stack traces were useful in this case.